# I want to select(star select) only one course in this. But it is in for loop so all are selecting once i click

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

In image once i clicked all courses are getting select, but i want to select only one course( with star)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import{CourseService} from './course.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `   

    <h2>Courses</h2>
    {{title}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#course of courses; #index=index">
            <a (click)="onClick()">
                <span>
                    <i class="glyphicon"
                        [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
                        [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
                        (click)="onClick()">    
                    </i>  
                    {{ course }}
                </span>
            </a>     
        </li>
    </ul>`
    providers: [CourseService]
})
export class CoursesComponent {

    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;   

    constructor(courseService: CourseService){
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    } 

    isActive = true;

    onClick($event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
        console.log("Clicked", $event);     
    }    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Stop an event"?

Comment: And for the next question you want to ask: Please format your code accordingly.

Comment: What's the problem? What's the current behavior? What's the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

All your lines bind to the same `isFavorite` field. Fields in the component are not generated for each item in `*ngFor`. There is only one.

To work around, make it an

**array**

```
    <li *ngFor="#course of courses; let index=index">
        <a (click)="onClick()">
            <span>
              <i class="glyphicon"
                [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite[index]"
                [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite[index]"
                (click)="onClick(index)">    
              </i>
```

```
export class CoursesComponent {

    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;  
    isFavorite; 

    constructor(courseService: CourseService){
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
        this.isFavorite = new Array(this.courses.length);
    } 

    isActive = true;

    onClick(index){
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.isFavorite[index] = !this.isFavorite;
    }    
}
```

or an
**object**

```
<i class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite[course]"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite[course]"
    (click)="onClick(course)">    
</i>
```

```
export class CoursesComponent {

    title = "The title of courses page";
    courses;  
    isFavorite = {}; 

    constructor(courseService: CourseService){
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    } 

    isActive = true;

    onClick(course){
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.isFavorite[course] = !this.isFavorite;
    }    
}
```